# How to change routing for skype packets?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, skype

I can't seem to find a way to somehow change routing for Skype packets.

I have following situation:

host ha, in lan, runs skype.

host ha has gateway "gw1"

gw1 has 2 separate network connections - one of them is default, and I'd like to dedicate the other for skype connections.

All machines involved use Linux, so I can change/set anything I want.

Is there any way to mark skype packets somehow to be able to change its routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use Snort IDS and fwsnort (to generate rules) in order to do what you need. With a little looking around, I also found [Application Layer Packet Classifier for Linux](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/) which might do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that Skype (and many other P2P-esque apps like it) don't use a set of known ports for their traffic, this is a difficult problem to solve. In order to identify and tag Skype packets, you'll need some sort of appliance or application that performs deep packet inspection (DPI). To my knowledge, there's nothing freely-available in linux that will be able to identify Skype traffic, though that may be incorrect.